# Compare datetime using CASE

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table of start time and end time of an event that takes place in the real world.

I believe the data type of the start time and end time is of the datetime/timestamp type inside the db. It is definitely not a string.

The records in the table look something like the below:

```
id |     start time      | end time
1  | 2020-08-18 10:00:00 | 2020-08-18 11:00:00
2  | 2020-08-18 19:00:00 | 2020-08-18 20:00:00
3  | 2020-08-18 05:00:00 | 2020-08-18 06:00:00
```

Right now, I am trying to do something like a classification to see if the event take place before / during/ after 'office/work hours'.

The column `SamplingStart` is the start time of the event.
The column `SamplingEnd` is the end time of the event.

Below is a portion of my query written in MySQL:

```
CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(b01.SamplingStart, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(b01.SamplingEnd, '%Y-%m-%d') AND b01.Speed * 3.6 >= 5 THEN

      CASE 
            WHEN TIME(b01.SamplingStart) >= '08:00:00' AND TIME(b01.SamplingEnd) <= '17:00:00'  THEN "During office hours"
            WHEN TIME(b01.SamplingStart) >= '17:01:00' AND TIME(b01.SamplingEnd) <= '23:59:00'  THEN "After office hours"
            WHEN TIME(b01.SamplingStart) >= '00:01:00' AND TIME(b01.SamplingEnd) <= '07:59:00'  THEN "Before office hours"
      END
    WHEN b01.Speed = 0 THEN "No Usage"
END AS VUsage
```

My thought process was like this. I first determine if the start time and end time are of the **same day** and don't care about the time part of the datetime column. If they are of the same day. Then I just have to compare the hours to see if they are before/after office hours within the same day.

The way the code above written seemingly fulfills most of my records in the database table and I can get the string representation for most of my rows in the table.

But something wrong occurs for some specific time ranges. When the start time is for example 17 Aug 2020 11pm and the end time for that record is 18 Aug 2020 8:05am then the result of my query returns a blank for that particular row.

I guess this is because 17 Aug 11pm is the 'after hours', however the end time is 18 Aug 8:05am which  is the 'before hours' range. I am guessing that because there is conflict, that is why the result for the particular row in the table is blank.

I was thinking the way to overcome this is to think that if the start time and end time are of a different day. i.e. 17 aug vs 18 aug. I can 'assume' that this is after hours. This feels slightly wrong. I am not 100% sure.

I also have a feeling that they may be other time frames which my CASE statement inside my SQL code cannot properly catch and resulting in a blank classification.

I feel that I may have missed out something and wanted to know if there a better/cleverer way for this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: _I believe the data type of the start time and end time is some sort of timestamp inside the db. It is not a string._ Can you not be sure?

Comment: @RiggsFolly , it is definitely not a string data type.

Comment: If an event can overlap over *before / during/ after 'office/work hours'* then the question *if the event take place before / during/ after 'office/work hours'* is not suitable.

Comment: @forpas , are you trying to say that I should think about the real world situation properly before trying to write a piece of SQL code which is inadequate?

Comment: Usually the question provides a clear requirement with expected results. Do you have to provide expected results for your requirement? What happens when an event overlaps with more than 1 of the intervals:  before / during/ after 'office/work hours? This is something that you have to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could safely say

```
WHEN TIME(b01.SamplingStart) >= '08:00:00' AND TIME(b01.SamplingEnd) <= '17:00:00'  THEN "During office hours"
WHEN TIME(b01.SamplingStart) >= '17:00:01' THEN "After office hours"
WHEN TIME(b01.SamplingStart) >= '00:00:01' AND TIME(b01.SamplingEnd) <= '07:59:59' THEN "Before office hours"
```

If all you want to know is when the event started to signify After or Before office hours

Note I also made the time more precise so you dont miss any events